# For self-hosted weaviate instances, how many schemas and classes are allowed?

Tags: class, schema, weaviate

Looking to better understand how to monitor instance capacity as bootstrapped self-hoster, in other words, how much overhead should I allow?

Specifically,

What is the limit on:

1. schemas,
2. classes,
3. total data (per container)?

Set up single docker hosted image and looking to add more nodes and capacity, when and if required.